# How to change brightness in iOS 5 app?

Tags: ios5, brightness, screen-brightness, uiscreen

How would I program the ability to change brightness in-app? I know that its possible as I have seen at least three apps that can do it. This would be very useful for my app. I know that it's only possible in iOS 5 with the UIScreen Class, but I have no idea how to program it. Please help me!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The `UIScreen` class has a new [property called `brightness`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScreen/brightness).

In addition, there's another property called `wantsSoftwareDimming` that (when set to `YES`) allows you to go below the lowest brightness supported by the hardware, because a special "dimming view" is overlaid over the screen to darken things even further.

The `brightness` property takes a float from `0` to `1`.  So:

- with `wantsSoftwareDimming` set to `NO` (the default), a `brightness` of `0` means "the darkest the hardware supports" and a `brightness` of `1` means "the brightest the hardware supports".
- with `wantsSoftwareDimming` set to `YES`, a `brightness` of `0` means "the darkest the hardware supports PLUS darkening by overlaying a dimming view", and a `brightness` of `1` still means "the brightest the hardware supports".

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I didn't know about the 'wantsSoftwareDimming' option, but it helps my app a lot!

Answer (score 13):

I have never tried it, but looking at the docs it should go like this:

```
UIScreen *mainScreen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
mainScreen.brightness = .5; //should set the brightness at 50%
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either of these two:

1. `[[UIScreen mainScreen]setBrightness:1.0];`
2. `GSEventSetBacklightLevel(0.5f);` But this is a private API call, if you use it, your application will surely be rejected.

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out you can use

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:1.0];
```

**BUT** be very careful because you will run into problems (talking from experience here)
look at this: 
[IOS5 setBrightness didn't work with applicationWillResignActive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280734/ios5-setbrightness-didnt-work-with-applicationwillresignactive)
and this:
[Anyone been able to use [[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness] on background / exit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997375/anyone-been-able-to-use-uiscreen-mainscreen-setbrightness-on-background-ex)

(I wish I had, when I discovered this thread/answer) :-(