# Anyone been able to use [[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness] on background / exit?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

There appears to be a previously documented (and reported) bug in iOS (which still, it appears to exist in 'the latest iOS') which means that while you can use [[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:x] once the Application has started you can not call it at any time during the backgrounding event (which means you can't RESTORE brightness to the level it was at before your app started).

```
// Works as expected, screen dims
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"applicationDidBecomeActive");

    // Dim the screen (works)
    [[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:0.2];
}
```

But...

```
// Seems to fire if you double-tap the home key ('task manager' ;)
// Doesn't work
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"applicationWillResignActive");

    [[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:1.0];
}
```

The background to this is I'm porting my successful Dock Clock app from Android to iOS and have now discovered that I can not restore screen brightness.  It's obviously a bug but I wondered if anyone has discovered a work-around?

Here's a very simple prototype test app which proves the bug:

https://github.com/philask/Dockclock-iOS

Comment: You are not discussing beta OS features here on SO, are you?

Comment: Not unless you consider iOS 4.0 still in Beta.. then no.

Comment: Ah, that is why you removed the mention of that beta in your latest edit... -.-

Comment: So are you here to help or troll?

Comment: Not sure if you are trying to provoke or if you simply ignore the rules without knowing any better. Anyways, my initial comment was an attempt to prevent you from breaking the Apple NDA you have accepted. Breaking the NDA will get your account suspended.

Comment: Any luck?  I doing something similar but ran into the same problem.  Heck, even `[UIScreen mainScreen].brightness = 1.0;` doesn't work.

Comment: Bug still not fixed in IOS 6.1.4

Comment: Still not fixed in iOS 7.0.4

Comment: Still not fixed in iOS 8.3

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try to restore it when my app enter the background .. but I notice that it will be restored when you lock and unlock the device.

Comment: Deeper diving in the Apple developer forums shows this is clearly a bug.  Intention is that the app can use setBrightness however it likes  and the OS will deal with restoring brightness on switch / background (as Android does).  So it's a bug, and I've logged a bug report with Apple (although I understand so have a few hundred other developers).

Comment: So is there a way to restore brightness at the end of an application or when it goes to background ??

Comment: Can confirm this for IOS 6.1.4